# Why marked state still be negative after inversion about mean (Grover's search)?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-state, grovers-algorithm

From my understanding, after phase flip only the marked state will be negative and every state should be positive. But it's not.


I think my initial state [image]
And marked state[image]
Are correct.

And after inversion about mean, i think it should inverse the marked state to around +5/8 and other state reduce to +3/8

but the marked state is -5/8 instead.
[image]

Does anyone have any idea about this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the code you've used to create and draw these circuits, along with the state you're looking for?

Comment: It’s hard to see see what you’re doing. The oracle should negate the marked state, and the diffuser should flip everything around the new mean.